# Scrolls are not displayed for kendo grid in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, scrollbar, microsoft-edge

Scrolls are not displayed for kendo grid in Microsoft Edge browser. It works properly when viewed in Google chrome.
I used Kendo UI property Virtual Scrolling set to true but it shows Vertical scrollbar but not horizontal one.

```
 scrollable: {
            virtual: true
        },
```

so is there any other kendo property available to show horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: did you add overflow-x to it by any chance?

Comment: i tried the above mentioned, but did not work. also tried overflow-scroll and overflow-auto that too did not work.